# Accepting DataTable changes in a DataGridView_RowsRemoved event handler throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.5

I have a DataGridView that is bounded to a DataTable datasource:

```
this.ImdToImportDataGridView.DataSource = this._imdToImportDataTable;
```

I allow users to delete lines, one at a time, by pressing <kbd>DEL</kbd> key.

Since I don't need to commit those changes to a DB or other storage, I handled the DataGridView_RowsRemoved event with the following code:

```
private void ImdToImportDataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    this._imdToImportDataTable.AcceptChanges();
}
```

This causes a never-ending chain of exception like the following:

```
---------------------------
DataGridView Default Error Dialog
---------------------------
The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 1 does not have a value.
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)

To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.
```

If I insert a delay, all goes fine but I hate this approach:

```
private void ImdToImportDataGridView_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Avoid IndexOutOfRangeException
        Task.Delay(10);
        this._imdToImportDataTable.AcceptChanges();
    });
}
```

It seems that the DataGridView hasn't still fully updated when the event is fired.

Any solutions?

Comment: _Since I don't need to commit those changes to a DB or other storage,..._ Then don't call it? or handle the `DataTable` events instead. See [DataTable.RowDeleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.rowdeleted?view=net-7.0).

Comment: If you insist on calling `AcceptChanges()`, for some reason (you didn't say why you'd need that at this time), mark the event handler `async` and just `await Task.Delay()`, removing `Task.Run()` which may cause other issues. Or simply `BeginInvoke()` the method -- But, it would be better if you could explain why you're doing this

Comment: @Jimi sorry for the big delay. `BeginInvoke` seems to start an infinite loop that block the UI. `async` + `await Task.Delay()` initially seems to work but then it then causes flickers and problems with other UI components on the form.

Comment: @dr.null @Jimi Why I want to `AcceptChanges`? Simply because when the user closes the form I need to read from the bound datatable and do things... and I don't want those zombie records in the way.

Comment: _when the user closes the form I need to read from the bound datatable and do things..._ Then forget the `RowsRemoved` event and call `AcceptChanges` just before that? Also, you might find the [`GetChanges(DataRowState)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.getchanges?view=net-7.0#system-data-datatable-getchanges(system-data-datarowstate)) method useful.